# Google maps logo position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

Is there a way to change the position of the Google logo that is displayed on the map tiles of a Google map?

Looking at different Google maps examples I see it being placed bottom left but also bottom center:

[image: Google logo bottom left corner]
[image: Google logo bottom center]

I have a Google map where the position of the Google logo is to the bottom left. I have a sidebar on this map that is placed above the logo so the logo isn't completely visible and this is violating Googles terms of use. I would therefore like to move if to the bottom center. Is it possible?

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvoters of this question commented to explain why they think this is a poor question, and importantly, how it can be improved.

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968399/can-i-overlay-google-logo-on-map-or-move-it-to-top-right) out?